# SPA - item queue management. client or server side?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, queue, single-page-application

I am working on a SPA.
The website has a queue for user selected items (from search result that can potentially be very large).
This queue will only live as long as the browser window/tab.
Should I manage user selected items in the client memory without cookies or (ajax) submit the selected items every time user make change to the list and click on a button such as "extract".

*We don't want to use cookie to store the selected item because the list can get really long and we don't want to have overhead from cookie.

Thanks,

Comment: if its temporary user related information, why not store it in localStorage or indexedDB? if this user related information does not have to persisted across sessions, there is no point making all the ajax calls to store data you won't need in the future.

Comment: Agree.
I suggested to store selected item by it's id and other unique identifiers in js variable that persist throughout the lifetime of the window.
I doubt there will be memory issues on the client side even if the list contains over 10,000 ids+identifiers.